# I want to show form validation error messages below input fields

Tags: codeigniter, view, controller

I want to show error right below the input fields in codeigniter. Here my code

```
if(isset($_POST['register'])){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','E-mail','required|callback_check_email|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|min_length[5]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2','Conform Password','required|min_length[5]|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', 'phone' ,'required|min_length[11]');
        if($this->form_validation->run() ==TRUE){
            echo "Form  validated";
            {
                $array = array
                (
                    'success' => '<div class="alert alert-success">Thanks for Sign Up</div>'
                );
            }


            //connect with db for inserting data
            $data = array(
                'username'=> $this->input->post('username'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' =>  md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'created_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'phone' => $this->input->post('phone')
            );


            $insert_id = $this->auth->insert_user($data);

                if($insert_id)
                {

                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Your Account has been registerd");
                    redirect("login", "refresh");
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Error While Creating Account");
                    redirect("register", "refresh");

                }

        }
        else
            {
                $array = array
                (
                    'error' => TRUE,
                    'username-error' => form_error('username'),
                    'email-error' => form_error('email'),
                    'password-error' => form_error('password'),
                    'conpass-error' => form_error('password2'),
                    'phone-error' => form_error('phone')
                );
            }

    }
    $this->load->view('register','$array');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the form error below the input field it corresponds to

In your view (for each of the inputs):

```
<input name="something" value="">
<?php echo form_error('something'); ?>
```

You can also test if `empty(form_error('something'))` if you needed that for some conditional logic.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code:

```
$this->load->view('register','$array');
```

To:

```
$this->load->view('register',$array);
```

and in view file it should show something like :

```
<?php echo form_error('username-error'); ?> and so on..
```